# Github Pages - only some files are accessible

Tags: github, github-pages

I Ihave this GitHub repository: https://github.com/photopea/Typr.js/

"demo/index.html" is accessible over HTTP:

https://photopea.github.io/Typr.js/demo/index.html

However, "src/Typr.js" is not:

https://photopea.github.io/Typr.js/src/Typr.js

Why is the folder "demo" accessible, but the folder "src" is not?

Answer (score 0):

Your URL is for `src/Typr.html` which does not exist in the repository. [`src/Typr.js`](https://photopea.github.io/Typr.js/src/Typr.js) is accessible.

Comment: Sorry, I meant src/Typr.js . So I just checked your URL from Uptrends, and it seems it is accessible everywhere except of Prague (that is where I am) https://imgur.com/Z2qG2Qr

Comment: @IvanKuckir Works For Me™ Try `curl https://photopea.github.io/Typr.js/src/Typr.js` to see if it's your browser or something else.

Comment: I checked the URL at https://www.uptrends.com/tools/uptime  and it does not work in Prague where I am https://imgur.com/Z2qG2Qr . Do you know what could be the reason?

Comment: @IvanKuckir My only guess is it could be a [CDN caching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network) issue. I'd suggest you contact Github support.